# msbuild won't build in release configuration

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

Using msbuild 14.0 and calling it from the command:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe C:\Project\MySolution.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform='Any CPU'`

*MySolution* is a Visual Studio C# solution and consists of several projects: *Project1*, *Project2*, ...

Output:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 2018-06-08 10:48:08 AM.
Project "C:\Project\MySolution.sln" on node 1 (Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform='Any CPU
' target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
ValidateProjects:
  The project "Project3" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
C:\Project\MySolution.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:
Platform='Any CPU'" does not exist in the project. [C:\Project\MySolution.sln]
Done Building Project "C:\Project\MySolution.sln" (Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform='Any
 CPU' target(s)) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.
```

- Why does msbuild not build the solution in **release** configuration? It always defaults to **debug**?? The solution is configured properly and has no problems building with that configuration when called from Visual Studio.
- msbuild always picks out *Project3* and claims that it *is not selected for building in solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU"* which is not true. All projects in this solution can also be build in debug configuration. But this is not what I'm trying to do here.

Screenshot of the solution's configuration:

[image: Screenshot of the solution's configuration]

The two unchecked projects at the bottom of the list are unit tests.

---

Additional question:

- How can I integrate the `/verbosity` switch into the build command?

Comment: Could be that the solution does not have a Release configuration?

Comment: It has one and I'm using it regularly from Visual Studio.

Comment: Or as the message informs us, the checkbox for build is not checked.

Comment: Yes, you're right, _Project3_ shall not be build in debug configuration. I checked the box but the error still remains: `C:\Project\MySolution.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:
Platform='Any CPU'" does not exist in the project. [C:\Project\MySolution.sln]`. Also it's not the point building in **debug** configuration, it shall use **release** configuration!

Comment: Would this help? https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1109834/Error-MSB-The-target-Package-does-not-exist-in-t

Comment: /verbosity:diag... You can specify the following verbosity levels: q[uiet], m[inimal], n[ormal], d[etailed], and diag[nostic]. from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of msbuild 14.0 I used msbuild 15.0 (I'm targeting framework 4.6.1 anyway) and the errors were gone.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add this additional property with your command and check.

```
/p:TargetFramework=<version>
```

Comment: Error persists - I use framework version 4.6.1 as specified in the Visual Studio project.

Answer (score 0):

From the list box where you select debug/release click on "Configuration Manager" and check that for the Solution release configuration all of your projects are setted to "Release" -> "AnyCPU".
 [image]

Hope This Help,
Legion

---

2nd Question Answer:

```
/fileLogger1 /fileLoggerParameters:LogFile=MyLog.log;Append; Verbosity=diagnostic;Encoding=UTF-8
```

or

```
/verbosity:diagnostic
```